# Not the right Xstream converter selected by Cucumber

Tags: java, xstream, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I've been using Cucumber for dozens of Java projects so far an never encountered this issue before, so I'm a bit puzzled.

I have a simple table that I want to map to a List in my step definition.

```
  And deal repository contains
  | dealPid | closingDate | expenseCode |
  | 1       | 01/06/2015  | test        |
```

I started by creating my own POJO with only required fields, following standard camel case convention (getters/setters are omitted for clarity)

```
public class Deal {

     private String dealPid ;
     private Date closingDate ;
     private String expenseCode;
}
```

my step definition :

```
@Given("^deal repository contains$")
public void deal_repository_contains(
        @Format("dd/MM/yyyy") List<DEAL> deals) throws Throwable {
...
}
```

Fields get mapped properly and I'm getting a List with one Deal item, fine. When I go in debug, up to cucumber.runtime.xstream.LocalizedXStreams

```
Converter converter = converterLookup.lookupConverterForType(clazz);
```

I see a xStream **ReflectionConverted** gets selected for the Datatable parsing.

This is a legacy project, and other developers then told me there was already a class existing for this. So now I want to switch to that class, that follows really strange conventions : class name is the table name on which it's mapped in DB, and most of the attributes names are actually the column names..

So now I'm using this legacy DEAL class from another package in my step definition, so I'm expecting a List to come up, but it doesn't. I get a List but even first row gets parsed. In debug, I see the converter that gets selected is a **DynamicClassWithStringAssignableConverter** instead of a ReflectionConverter previously, which is why the parsed result is different in the end.

Unfortunately, I'm unable to go further in debug and understand why this implementation gets selected, as Xstream is repackaged in cucumber-jvm-deps and Eclipse gets lost (or I don't know how to attach sources correctly in that case).

I tried adding temporarily the fields I need with proper names (ie same as in my initial Deal class) in DEAL class, but it doesn't work. 
Initially, DEAL class was implementing Serializable : I removed it, but still the same behavior.

It actually looks like because the class name is full upper case, a different Xstream converter gets selected...

Can it really be the root cause of the issue ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just hit this very surprising behaviour myself - in my case the issue turned out to be that `DynamicClassWithStringAssignableConverter.canConvert` returns `true` if the type to be converted has a constructor that takes a single, `String` argument.

Work around was to remove the constructor!